# Properties of holomorphic function having convergent Laurent series in some domain

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

While trying assignment problems of complex analysis I am unable to solve this particular question and so I am posting it here.

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on $0<|z|<\epsilon$ , $\epsilon >0$ given by convergent Laurent series $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_{n} z^{n}$ .
Given also that $\lim_{z\to0} |f(z)|= \infty$ .

Then which one is true.

1. $a_{-1} \neq 0 $ and $a_{-n}  =0$ for all $n\ge 2$.
2. $a_{-N} \neq 0 $ for some $N>1$ and $a_{-n}=0$ for all $n >N$ .
3. $a_{-n} =0$ for all $n>0$.
4. $a_{-n} \neq 0$  for all $n>0$.

Although I have studied Ch- Laurent series from text book Complex variables with applications by Ponnusamy and Silvermanbut I am completely clueless on how this particular problem can be approched.

Can anyone please shed some light.

Comment: Hint: what kind of singularity does $f$ have at $0$?  Removable, pole or essential?

Comment: $z^2/f(z)$ is holomorphic on a small disk

Comment: @Robert Israel I think it's essential singularity. But can you please ellaborate on how it might be useful?

Comment: No, $|f|$ can't go to $\infty$ at an essential singularity (see the Casorati-Weierstrass theorem).

Comment: @Robert Israel Statement of Casorati Weirestrauss theorem is that : If f(z) has an essential singularity at z=$z_{0}$ , then f(z) comes arbitrary close to every complex value in each deleted neighborhood of $z_{0}$ . So, I think it can approach $\infty$ .

Comment: If it's coming arbitrarily close to a particular number, it doesn't have limit $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively f(z)=1/z which satisfy given conditions in this way options (3) and (4) are wrong.If you consider f(z)=1/z² this will discard option (1). Hence, option (2) is correct.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).